# DataSet normalize range of input values

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, normalization, tensorflow-datasets

I'm running some experiments with neural networks in TensorFlow. The release notes for the latest version say DataSet is henceforth the recommended API for supplying input data.

In general, when taking numeric values from the outside world, the range of values needs to be normalized; if you plug in raw numbers like length, mass, velocity, date or time, the resulting problem will be ill-conditioned; it's necessary to check the dynamic range of values and normalize to the range `(0,1)` or `(-1,1)`.

This can of course be done in raw Python. However, DataSet provides a number of data transformation features and encourages their use, on the theory that the resulting code will not only be easier to maintain, but run faster. That suggests there should also be a built-in feature for normalization.

Looking over the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets however, I'm not seeing any mention of such. Am I missing something? What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to normalize across the whole dataset or inside each element ? Inside each element should be easy using `dataset.map` but I can't think of an easy way to do it across the whole dataset unless you know beforehand the maximum and minimum values that your values can take.

Comment: @Sunreef Right, that's the thing, it has to be across the whole dataset, because there's no way of knowing how to do it before looking at all the values that actually occur.

Comment: @nwallace With Tensorflow lazy-loading, I'm not sure you can get access to all your values unless you add a preprocessing step where you only iterate through the whole dataset, extract max and min, then use this information in a second step when training. But you'd be better off just using normal Numpy to get these values.

Comment: @nwallace I guess you could implement something like a rolling max where you update your max value with each batch fed to the network. Your first epoch might be wrong at the beginning because small values will be over-estimated but if you're planning on training for 10 or more epochs, the error will correct itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of tensorflow datasets main idea tells me that complex pre-procesing is not directly applicable, because [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) is specifically designed to *stream* very large amounts of data, more precisely tensors:

> A `Dataset` can be used to represent an input pipeline as a collection
>   of elements (nested structures of tensors) and a "logical plan" of
>   transformations that act on those elements.

The fact that `tf.data.Dataset` operates with *tensors* means that obtaining any particular statistic over the data, such as `min` or `max`, requires a complete `tf.Session` and at least one run through the whole pipeline. The following sample lines:

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch_x, batch_y = iterator.get_next()
```

... which are designed to provide the next batch fast, no matter of the size of the dataset, would stop the world until the first batch is ready, if the `dataset` is responsible for pre-processing.  That's why the "logical plan" includes only local transformations, which ensures the data can be streamed and, in addition, allows to do transformations [in parallel](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map).

This doesn't mean it's impossible to implement the normalization with `tf.data.Dataset`, I feel like it's never been designed to do so and, as a result, it will look ugly (though I can't be absolutely sure of that). However, note that [batch-normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) fits into this picture perfectly, and it's one of the "nice" options I see. Another option is do simple pre-processing in numpy and feed the result of that into `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. This doesn't make the pipeline much more complicated, but doesn't restrict you from using `tf.data.Dataset` at all.